# Верно ли согласован причастный оборот?

Tags: причастный-оборот

Сроки пересчета стоимости активов и обязательств, выраженной в иностранной валюте, в рубли.

Comment: Если вам дан (или будет дан) исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Comment: Это заголовок колонки в таблице? Не похоже на самостоятельную фразу.

Comment: Да, это заголовок.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не важно, нарушены ли здесь формальные правила согласования или нет, но понять смысл такого предложения с первой попытки невозможно. Лучше перестроить это предложение любым понятным способом. Например:

**Сроки пересчета в рубли выраженной в иностранной валюте стоимости активов и обязательств.**

Это тоже не идеальный вариант, но для канцелярита вполне приемлемый. Надеюсь, кто-то предложит вариант получше.

**Дополнение**.

В ПБУ (положении по бухгалтерскому учёту) в большинстве случаев использована формулировка "**Пересчёт выраженной в иностранной валюте стоимости активов и обязательств**". Но несколько раз встретился также вариант построения фразы такой, как в вопросе. Мне мой вариант нравится больше, но я готов согласиться, что они оба допустимы.

Comment: *Это тоже не идеальный вариант* Это гораздо худший вариант.

Comment: @Niemand А чем он гораздо хуже?

Comment: Распространенное определение *перед* определяемым словом (и как следствие, отсутствие запятых).

Comment: @Niemand Я понял, что мы разошлись во вкусах. Но всё равно странно, что до такой (в смысле "гораздо") степени. Я дополнил ответ аргументами.

Comment: @Niemand Независимо от этого спора проголосовал за Ваш ответ, поскольку он лучше отвечает на заданный вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Согласован верно. Ведь в иностранной валюте выражена стоимость, а не активы и обязательства.